# Java graphics isn't repainting

Tags: java, graphics, awt, repaint, event-dispatch-thread

I want to add in a feature so that when the mouse goes over a button then it will add a drop shadow. Currently I'm just trying to get the mechanics to work. I have my game loop calling a update method which I know works but here it is anyway

```
    public void updateManager(double delta){
    mhandler.updateCoordinates();
    if(mhandler.getX() >= 144 && mhandler.getX() <= 444 && mhandler.getY() >= 784 && mhandler.getY() <= 980){
        oversp = true;
    }else{
        oversp = false;
    }
}
```

mhandler is what I named my MouseHandler class. 
then i have my render method

```
    public void render(){
    repaint();
}
```

and then my paint method

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    if(oversp){
        System.out.println("Is over button");
        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fillRect(144, 784, 300, 169);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Not over button");
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect(144, 784, 300, 169);
    }
}
```

When ever i run the program it only prints out not over button twice even when i am constantly calling render() in my game loop. I really do not know why it is not repainting. any help is very appriciated!

This is how I detect my coordinates of mouse

```
    private int x,y;

public MouseHandler(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

public void updateCoordinates(){
    PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
    Point b = a.getLocation();
    x = (int) b.getX();
    y = (int) b.getY();
}

public int getX(){
    return x;
}

public int getY(){
    return y;
}
```

Game loop code

```
    public static void MenuLoop() {
    long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
    final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
    final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;
    long lastFpsTime = 0;
    int fps = 0;
    while (isrunning) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
        lastLoopTime = now;
        double delta = updateLength / ((double) OPTIMAL_TIME);

        lastFpsTime += updateLength;
        fps++;

        if (lastFpsTime >= 1000000000) {
            System.out.println("(FPS: " + fps + ")");
            lastFpsTime = 0;
            fps = 0;
        }

        menu.render();
        menu.updateManager(delta);


        try {
            Thread.sleep((lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME) / 1000000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}public static void MenuLoop() {
    long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
    final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
    final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;
    long lastFpsTime = 0;
    int fps = 0;
    while (isrunning) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
        lastLoopTime = now;
        double delta = updateLength / ((double) OPTIMAL_TIME);

        lastFpsTime += updateLength;
        fps++;

        if (lastFpsTime >= 1000000000) {
            System.out.println("(FPS: " + fps + ")");
            lastFpsTime = 0;
            fps = 0;
        }

        menu.render();
        menu.updateManager(delta);


        try {
            Thread.sleep((lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME) / 1000000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could it be that your game loop is blocking the gui thread?

Comment: It has to be a problem with how you're detecting whether the mouse is inside or outside the button, but since we don't have code for that, it's not possible to troubleshoot at the moment.  Also - it would be much better to compare your mouse position against coordinates returned by the button itself instead of using absolute values for X and Y.

Comment: The Swing paint manager will coalesce your repaint() requests if they come fast and close. So number of `repaints` occurring is way less than expected.

Comment: this code missed super.paintComponent(g) (1st line) in paintComponent

Comment: If you're calling `render` inside an infinite loop on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), the EDT will be blocked and the GUI will be unresponsive (as already mentioned by @Heuster). If that's what your game loop looks like, you should rather use a [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). In any case, you could post the code for your game loop.

Comment: I added the game loop code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) contains a queue to which all AWT events are added. Whenever you call `repaint`, a paint event will be queued on the Event Dispatch Thread.

So if you're in an infinite loop while on the Event Dispatch Thread, those paint events will stand in line forever, waiting for the infinite loop to end. That's why `paintComponent` is never called.

The solution would be to replace the infinite loop with a [Swing timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000 / TARGET_FPS, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
    }
});
timer.start();
```